# Porque no me toma los datos existentes en la BD para iniciar la sesion?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sesiones

Pasa que... estoy trabajando en un crud con sesiones en java web + oracle.

Tengo mi base de datos con algunos "usuarios" existentes, y al momento de iniciar sesión me entra colocando cualquier cosa.

Cuando pruebo con breakpoints, en la conexion, ya sea preparedstatement, el resultset etc, me salen en null. No se exactamente en que me equivoqué.

[image: Ahi se ve claramente como me setea en null, a pesar de que otras cosas como listar otros datos, lo puede hacer correctamente]

La parte que me comienza a dar error es en el DAO que es donde tengo el tema de la conexion para poder realizar el "logueo".

La sesion funciona correctamente, pero bajo cualquier cosa que ponga, como algo temporal, no bajo los datos que existen en la BDD básicamente.

PD: Perdón si no logré explicarme muy bien. Saludos

```
public boolean login(String usuario, String password){
        boolean r = true;
        String sql="select * from Cuenta where usuario = '"+usuario+"' and pass = '"+password+"';";
        try{
            con = c.conectar();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);      

            if (ps.executeQuery()!= null){
                r = true;
            }else{
                r=false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERROR al intentar loguearse");
        }
        return r;
    }
```

**EDIT: otro problema con el codigo encontrado. Exactamente en el controlador. línea 80.**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //processRequest(request, response);

    HttpSession s = request.getSession();

    String user = request.getParameter("usuario");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    CuentaDAO cuDAO = new CuentaDAO();
    Cuenta c = new Cuenta();

    c.setUsuario(user);
    c.setPass(pass);
    try {
        if(cuDAO.login(user, pass)){ //**Línea del error**
            s.setAttribute("sesion", cuDAO);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("listar_empresas.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }else{
            request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
            request.setAttribute("mensaje", "ERROR. Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa exactamente? ¿Salta una excepción? ¿A qué punto de la ejecución del código cursos la captura de pantalla?

Comment: Así es, me tira la excepción que se ve en el codigo "error al intentar loguearse". El punto en que me aparece el problema es en el DAO, que es donde muestro el código.

Comment: Bien, haz *e.printstacktrace* y ves un menaje explicando qué error te da y dónde salta. Buscando por ese error es posible que encuentres la solución, y si no con esa información podremos ayudarte mejor m

Comment: Me aparecieron 2 errores, uno en el codigo q mostré exactamente en el ps.executeQuery(), y el otro problema es en el controlador (agregue el codigo a la publicación.)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ps.executeQuery() nunca te va dar null. Porque aunque no encuentre resultados te daría un ResultSet vacío.

Prueba de esta forma:

```
java.sql.ResultSet resultado = ps.executeQuery();
r = resultado.next();
```

El método next() después de la búsqueda te retorna verdadero si encontró algún resultado.